# CISCO pix/asa Shun command equivalent on Junos

Tags: juniper, cisco-asa, junos

does any one knows if there is some equivalent of the shun command on Juniper Junos OS?

> The shun command on the ASA Firewall appliance is used to block connections from an attacking host. Packets matching the values in the command are dropped and logged until the blocking function is removed manually or by the Cisco IDS sensor.
>
> The format of the command is as following:
>
> ASA# shun [source IP] [destination IP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are IP actions like - IP-Block, and IP-Close, something like -

```
ip-action {
   ip-block;
   target   source-address;}
```

Checkout the O'Reilly book - "Junos Security", chapters 7 & 8

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001633/ch13.html